# Fileupload - Endpoint and OpenAI Generation for the Service

Tags: angular, spring, primeng, openai-api

My Endpoint is a RestConroller with a Post-Method looking like this:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/xetra", consumes =  {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})

public @ResponseBody void importXetra(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

After OpenAI Generator i get the following signature for the endpoint:

```
public importXetra(importXetraRequest?: ImportXetraRequest, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined, context?: HttpContext}): Observable<any>;
public importXetra(importXetraRequest?: ImportXetraRequest, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined, context?: HttpContext}): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>;
public importXetra(importXetraRequest?: ImportXetraRequest, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined, context?: HttpContext}): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
public importXetra(importXetraRequest?: ImportXetraRequest, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: undefined, context?: HttpContext}): Observable<any> {
```

with

```
export interface ImportXetraRequest { 
file: Blob;
```

}

My formular looks like:

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" [customUpload]="true" (uploadHandler)="upload($event)">
<ng-template pTemplate="toolbar">
  <div class="py-1">Upload 1 Files</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
  <div>Custom UI to display a file</div>
</ng-template>
```

my upload implementation:

```
  upload (event : {files: Blob[]}) : void {
let file  = event.files[0] as File;
let request: ImportXetraRequest = ({} as any) as ImportXetraRequest;
request.file = file;
this.importEndpoint.importXetra(request).subscribe({
  next : (res : void) => console.log("imported"),
  error: (e: ErrorEvent) => console.error("error = " + e),
});
```

}

I don't know how exactly i can do the call to the backend, the backend says it is not a valid request. I get a 500-error.
It also seems that the payload is not set/empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the endpoint didn't have the correct MediaType Consumer:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/xetra", consumes =  {
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
})
```

solved the problem.